# Adding ssl to apache virtual host causes rails authlogic to throw a database exception

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-3.1, passenger

I'm working on a rails application. We are using Ruby 1.9.3p0 and Rails 3.1.3 on an Ubuntu server with apache and phusion passenger installed. Our app uses authlogic for authentication and an sqlite database. I'm trying to add ssl support.

I modified my apache virtual host file so ssl is enabled. I then browsed to the app over http and https. They both worked. I then added a redirect to my virtual host so all traffic sent over http is redirected to https. Now when I access my app, I get the following phusion error:

Error message:
You must establish a database connection before using acts_as_authentic

I can't figure out what's causing the error. Here's my apache configuration file with sensitive data changed:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin my.email@example.com
    ServerName my.domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certificatefile
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key/file
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM

    DocumentRoot /path/to/document/root
    RailsEnv production
    <Directory /path/to/document/root>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    </Directory>

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my.email@example.com
    ServerName my.domain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. The auth_logic error was a red herring. The problem arose when I changed my ruby environment variable to production. The production sqlite database was not populated because everything was done in the development database up until this point. Thanks anyway.